# Date and Time picker issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I previously had this code working, but now it doesn't for some strange reason.

Code for Date And Time Picker

```
btnDatePicker=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    btnTimePicker=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    txtDate=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.in_date);
    txtTime=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.in_time);

    btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        });

    btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(),
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SELECT DATE"
        android:id="@+id/btn_date"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/in_date" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/in_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/in_date"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SELECT TIME"
        android:id="@+id/btn_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_date"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_time"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Medication:"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error Log

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112)
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82)
                  at com.example.shakeel.appidea2.calendar.CalendarFragment$1.onClick(CalendarFragment.java:118)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21328)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
                  at com.example.shakeel.appidea2.calendar.CalendarFragment$1.onClick(CalendarFragment.java:118) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21328) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
                  at com.example.shakeel.appidea2.calendar.CalendarFragment$1.onClick(CalendarFragment.java:118) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21328) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class TextView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:118)
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160)
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140)
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126)
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
                  at com.example.shakeel.appidea2.calendar.CalendarFragment$1.onClick(CalendarFragment.java:118) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21328) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class TextView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:118) 
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160) 
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140) 
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126) 
                  at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
                  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
                  at com.example.shakeel.appidea2.calendar.CalendarFragment$1.onClick(CalendarFragment.java:118) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21328) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
               Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; index=268
                  at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
                  at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1151)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:158)
                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1005)
                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:703)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:60)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDeleg
```

I'm not too sure on how to fix it, it was working perfectly before but I dont know what happened. I just updated android studio, then everything stopped working in my code, i've tried clean/rebuild and resync but still nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I Solved my problem.

The problem was located within my styles.xml file. I was playing about with changing the colour of the app, but by adding a colour accent to a theme caused everything to break. Not too sure why. If someone can explain why adding a colour accent would cause such a problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering this with getActivity instead of getContext this is most likely whats causing the inflation issue.

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

DATE PICKER

```
package course.examples.UI.datepicker;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DatePickerActivity extends Activity {
   private TextView mDateDisplay;
   private Button mPickDate;
   private int mYear;
   private int mMonth;
   private int mDay;
   static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
     // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
   private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      // capture our View elements
      mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
      mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
      // add a click listener to the button
      mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
         }
      });
      // get the current date
      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      // display the current date (this method is below)
      updateDisplay();
   }

    // updates the date in the TextView
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

TIME PICKER

```
package course.examples.UI.timepicker;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
public class TimePickerActivity extends Activity {
   private TextView mTimeDisplay;
   private Button mPickTime;
   private int mHour;
   private int mMinute;
   static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
   // the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
   private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
      public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
         mHour = hourOfDay;
         mMinute = minute;
         updateDisplay();
      }
   };
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      // capture our View elements
      mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
      mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);
      // add a click listener to the button
      mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
         }
      });
      // get the current time
      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      // display the current date
      updateDisplay();
   }
   // updates the time we display in the TextView
   private void updateDisplay() {
      mTimeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
            .append(pad(mMinute)));
   }
   private static String pad(int c) {
      if (c >= 10)
         return String.valueOf(c);
      else
         return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
   }
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
      switch (id) {
      case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
         return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute,
               false);
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```